# Trying to get data with one fixed WHERE statement and another one which is optional

Tags: mysql

I'm working on something similiar to GlotPress.

I have two tables

**strings**

- hash (primary key)
- original (text)
- project (foreign key)

**translations**

- hash
- string (foreign key)
- translation (text)
- language (ex.: en, fr, es)

What I want:

print every string including its translation in case it exists for a single project and language.
*Example*: I want every french translations + non-translated strings of a project.

This is what I have / I tried with:

```
SELECT * FROM strings 
LEFT JOIN translations ON strings.hash = translations.string 
WHERE strings.project = 'kg6k34j6'
AND language = 'fr'
OR language = NULL
```

Here's the problem: I cannot use the `OR` here, because all strings from every project will be shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM strings 
LEFT JOIN translations ON strings.hash = translations.string AND language = 'fr'
WHERE strings.project = 'kg6k34j6'
```

Comment: Oh damn, I think this was the only thing I didn't tested / searched for. Thanks!